# How can I properly link my SQL Server database to an Access form and distribute it to the network and have them input information?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

When I link the Microsoft Access to SQL Server locally, everything works. The second I go to a computer that is on the network, I am not able to open the form I created on the Access database.

I found out that if I open the link, I will get an error. If I choose where the DB through configurations in Access, I get the error again.  If I try this a third time, it connects to the database and it is fully linked--I am able to type data into Access and it will store it in the SQL Server database as well.

My question is: How do I get it to connect to the server on the first try? I have to hit "connect" three times which takes about 5 minutes to log in.  That isn't very efficient when the people using this program nothing about computers.

Comment: In order for us to help, it would be helpful to know **what exactly that error is** that you're getting... otherwise we're limited to crystal balls and mind reading - both rather unreliable....

Answer (score 0):

Linking Access to SQL Server uses ODBC.  Make sure your ODBC settings are correct.

Comment: Why would anybody recommend an ADP these days? MS has been deprecating them in favor of MDB/ACCDB/ODBC for nearly five years, and there have been no changes to ADPs in the last two versions of Access. That generally indicates that ADPs are on the way out...

Comment: The question is not about ADPs, is it?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton If you have a better answer, please post it and I will vote for it.

Comment: Why do I have to post an answer in order to be able to point out a weakness in YOUR answer (i.e., you recommend a path that MS deprecates)?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I'm not arguing (and I'm not going to argue) weaknesses in my answer.  I'm simply encouraging you to post an answer so that we can have something better.  *Clearly* you have better ideas than I do regarding this issue.

Comment: Your first suggestion is FINE, but your second IS NOT. There is nothing left for me to post, as all the appropriate answers have already been tendered.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton  Aah! I see where you're coming from not.  Fair enough. I'll remove that second line.  (Granted, it makes this a trivial answer.)